Visual Studio Code for ModusToolbox™ flashing issue
Using Visual Studio Code with Modus Toolbox™, we built the LED example project and successfully flashed the code in visual studio. Subsequently, we attempted to use Visual Studio Code as a flashing tool for a project generated by CMake.
Steps to be done:

We flashed the in-built ELF file, and it worked as expected.
Then, we tried to integrate a CMake-generated project into this workflow.
In the JSON configuration file, we updated the paths for the ELF and HEX files generated by CMake.
we encountered an issue where we were unable to flash the ELF file generated by CMake using Visual Studio Code.
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue?

I want to debug the Visual Studio code in any other cmake generated elf file.
